# .NET Core Azure WebJobs does not read from Azure Application Settings

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs, webjob

I have an app service running with it's respective ConnectionString from Azure Portal. The ConnectionString is point to Azure SQL Server.
[image: Azure Portal Application Settings for Connection String]

I have a WebJob with the following appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Add your connection string"
  }
}
```

When I run the Web Job, it doesn't seem to pull the Connection strings from the azure portal, but it uses my default ConnectionStrings in appsettings.json.

```
[02/13/2017 08:45:27 > 2942c6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[02/13/2017 08:45:27 > 2942c6: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[02/13/2017 08:45:27 > 2942c6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[02/13/2017 08:45:27 > 2942c6: INFO] 
[02/13/2017 08:45:27 > 2942c6: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TestConnectionString\32vmiek4.2av>dotnet TestConnectionString.dll 
[02/13/2017 08:45:29 > 2942c6: INFO] Add your connection string
```

Comment: What specific .NET Core version are you using? Also are you using VS2015 Update 3 or VS2017 RC1 or others?

Comment: Hi @juvchan I am using .NET Core 1.0.3 and VS 2017 RC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you call `AddEnvironmentVariables()` when building your configuration. e.g.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```